# Can't change Laravel table column type

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, mariadb

I cannot execute migrate:fresh.

Command fails at changing table column from:

```
$table->string('language_id')->default('')->length(255);
```

to:

```
$table->integer('language_id')->unsigned()->default(1)->change();
```

Error that I'm getting:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>      corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 1 NOT N
>     ULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE users CHANGE language_id language_id INT UNSIGNED CHA
>     RACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

**Any help/hints would be appreciated.**

Comment: Try to first set it to `integer` then set default value or vice versa

Comment: @ege same error appeared after changing to `$table->integer('language_id')->default(1)->unsigned()->change();`

Comment: I meant you are changing from `string` to `integer`. Maybe you need to remove some attributes of that field before changing it. Like `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` as it says in your error

Comment: Otherwise create new column. Migrate all your **reformatted** data there, then drop old column, and rename the current

Comment: @ege that is an appropriate solution, but current case does not allow me to do that. Changing string to unsigned int is the issue.

Comment: okay. How about this: try to change it using *phpmyadmin* or similar. copy the sql-queries it uses and use `DB::raw($query)` to add it to a migration file. It's laborious, but it might reveal what the issue is.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We have exact same problem.

Comment: @larsemil temporary working solution for my case was to leave it as string, and to use 1/0 values for the designated field so i can treat it as an unsigned integer, since i wasn't able to drop the column because it was populated with data. Maybe, writing a custom migration that will extract the data from the old table row and recreate the table row the right way could be a solution (make sure u backup the database first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the standard solution is not working. You can try this:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn  INTEGER;');
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn STRING;');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need doctrine/dbal

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

write a new migration & write this

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('language_id')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('your_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('language_id');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Laravel Documentation:

> Note: Before changing a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.

Try this

```
Schema::table('your_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('language_id')->default(1);
});
```

Comment: i can't drop the column, since i need to change column type without losing any stored values into table

Comment: Ok try without dropping the column

Comment: doctrine/dbal is included in composer, and without dropping the column same error occured

Comment: Maybe you have already some strings in your db ? And you want to change theme to Integer it's why you have this error